# Capacity planning for intranet portal of a large size global enterprise - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, capacity-planning

If a very large size farm wants to implement intranet portal which is having 20K user in each region e.g. North America, South America, Europe, Asia pacific region.
What can be feasible plan for data-center for this? Should they keep data center in each region?

What will be farm setup?

If company is willing to invest to avoid latency & other factors so how to plan to avoid those factors?

### How is this kind of setup planned in real life?

If for example they have different farms or different data centers in separate regions how is replication or synchronization happens between them?

Expecting answer from senior architects only

Comment: I must warn it is futile to have such expectations on a forum where people provide answer totally by free will, without any payment whatsoever, just to set your expectations straight! Benefit, learn if you can and move on, if it doesn't help, but be respectful regarding any effort whatsoever!

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommand you get support from an architect as the questions to be answered here go beyond those expressed here: e.g. what is the total volume of data, what is the quality of the WAN connection between locations, how would you plan to secure connections, what services you want to share/consume across locations, how is your AD structured, etc. -just answering those and many others will at least get you closed to establishing the type of Global deployment.

Further down, you need to perform capacity planning and assess required DR strategy, failover, databases mirroring/log shipping, scaling your farm(-s), decide if you need 1 farm or multiple farms, where do you stand on licenses, etc.

I assume you went through the diagrams on TechNet, so I won't shared them here again, I only warn that for such deployment it is worth getting an expert on-site to advise.